# Import set of text files to a set of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, text-editing

I have a set of text files named `outfile00.txt` until `outfile297.txt`. Each file has a number (decimal or otherwise) on every line except the first one (which is like a header).

I need to import the contents of each file to a column starting from column A (which will correspond to `outfile00.txt`) until all text files have been imported.

Here is a sample of the beginning of `outfile00.txt`:

```
KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.05
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

The actual file has about 1500 lines. I've tried manually importing the text file using the Data tab; Excel has no issues and the text is imported.

How can I import all the text files as a batch?

**EDIT**

I believe I had not defined my problem clearly, so here are some extra details.

With regards to [cybernard's](https://superuser.com/a/1110010/208847) method,

If I create a tab-separated values file (the tab character is between the letter and number on each line) as follows,

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
e   4
f   5
g   6
```

I can import the text file directly and get the following,

[image: Imported Tab-separated values file]

I was hoping to create a file similar to the aforementioned TSV file. An example would be as follows,

```
KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.05   KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.10   KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.15
0.00    117.00  123.00
0.00    118.00  124.00
0.00    119.00  125.00
0.00    120.00  126.00
```

which produces the following import results,

[image: Imported results from generated TSV file]

I need to know how I can generate such a TSV file from my source files.

Comment: Have you ever "recorded" a macro? You need, if not already, to enable the Developer's tab in Excel. A google search will solved the tab on how to. I did it so long ago I can't recall how to enable that feature. If you already know how to record a macro, then it's a matter of instantiating a counting varible; use a counter with a recorded macro of importing a text file. Press record, do a single import exactly how you want it. Press stop. Your macro is now recorded. Alt + F11 to examine the code. Modify the code. Test. Troubleshoot.

Comment: Here's another hint: dim counter as integer, dim mystring as String, counter = 1, mystgring = "C:/file" & cstr(counter) & ".txt"... if counter < 100 "file" & "00" & cstr(counter) &  ".txt". That hint should help you figure out a script to configure in your Macro. How to "for loop vba", "counter loop".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power Query to combine all files in a folder. Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transform.

Ken Puls has a detailed tutorial [here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/12/merge-multiple-files-with-properties/).

Once the query is set up, files can be added or removed from the folder and the query can be refreshed with the click of a button.

Comment: Thanks. I've read the tutorial but I can't seem to change each file to a different column. To make it worse, the tutorial mentioned `fnGetFileContents([Folder Path]&[Name])` in the custom column when it should be `File.Contents([Folder Path]&[Name])`. Spent some time solving that. I feel like I'm close to the solution though if I can just figure out having each file in its own column.

Comment: Just follow the tutorial. It works if you follow the steps. take your time.

Answer (score 0):

First 00 will have to be renamed 0.  You may have to remove other 0 offsets.  For example 01,02,03 won't work, rename to 1,2,3.

from the command prompt go into the folder containing all your files.

FOR /L %i IN (0,1,297) DO  type outfile%i.txt  >>master.txt

This should combine all your files into master.txt.

So you want a tab key between files.
In notepad, create a file that contains a single tab named tab.txt
after you save it ensure it is 1 byte in size, and you did accidentally hit other characters.

FOR /L %i IN (0,1,297) DO  type outfile%i.txt  tab.txt>>master.txt

Comment: To eliminate the hassle of renaming all files:

You could also use something like this:

 IF %i LSS 10 (type outfile00%i.txt) ELSE IF %i LSS 100 (type outfile0%i.txt) ELSE (type outfile%i.txt)

Comment: I think this solution would work if I could append the files after a tab character. From what I understand, it just piles one file after another so I end up with a really long master file. I've already had such a master file.

Comment: @KhalidHussain updated my answer so you can have your TAB character.

Comment: @cybernard, I've updated my answer to clarify where the `TAB` character should I occur. I hope I've understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** I need to know how I can generate such a TSV file from my source files.

Did you know there's a [command](https://ss64.com/bash/paste.html) just for that?

```
paste outfile*.txt > out.txt
```

If you want to write your own algorithm, pick the (scripting) language of your choice.

1. [`awk`](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/merge-columns-from-multiple-files-851336): `awk -f awk.awk outfile*.txt > out.txt`

   ```
   BEGIN {count = 1}
   FNR == 1 && FNR < NR {count++}

   {
     if ( _[FNR] ) {
       while ( c[FNR] != count-1 ) {
         _[FNR] = (_[FNR] " " sprintf("%8s",""))
         c[FNR]++
       }
       _[FNR] = (_[FNR] "\t" sprintf("%-8s",$0))
       c[FNR]++
     }
     else if ( count == 1 ) {
       _[FNR] = sprintf("%-8s",$0)
       c[FNR]++
     }
     else {
       while ( c[FNR] != count-1 ) {
         if ( _[FNR] )
           _[FNR] = (_[FNR] " " sprintf("%8s",""))
         else
           _[FNR] = sprintf("%8s","")
         c[FNR]++
       }
       _[FNR] = (_[FNR] "\t" sprintf("%-8s",$0))
       c[FNR]++
     }
   }

   END {
     for (i=1; i<=length(_); i++)
       print _[i]
   }
   ```
2. [`perl`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1145262): `perl perl.pl > out.txt`

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $i;
   my @rows;
   my @files = map { "outfile$_.txt" } 0 .. 297;

   foreach my $file (@files) {
       open my $infh, '<', $file or die $!;
       $i=0;
       while (<$infh>) {
           chomp;
           my $data = $_;
           if (length $rows[$i]) {
               $rows[$i++] .= "\t" . $data;
           } else {
               $rows[$i++] = $data;
           }
       }
   }

   foreach my $row (@rows) {
       print "$row\n";
   }
   ```

**P.S.** In case you're wondering, bash, awk and perl are available on several platforms, including Windows ([cygwin](https://cygwin.org) being my recommendation there).

**Update:** Here's the input files I used, together with the output of `paste outfile*.txt > out.txt` on [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io).

```
==> outfile00.txt <==
KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.05
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00

==> outfile01.txt <==
KP=1.50 ,Ki=1.10 ,Kd=1.05
1.00
1.00
1.00
1.00

==> out.txt <==
KP=0.50 ,Ki=0.10 ,Kd=0.05       KP=1.50 ,Ki=1.10 ,Kd=1.05
0.00    1.00
0.00    1.00
0.00    1.00
0.00    1.00
```

Comment: Interesting, although it doesn't produce the result I want. I've even tried with the `--serial` flag. Are you getting different results? I'm using the `paste` that came with Git Bash for Windows.

Comment: Could be due to the large number of files? Try first with just a few. There are three solutions posted here, and all have been tested with the sample data you provided. I suggest you enrich the *what I tried* section in your question showing the various outputs so we can all see where you got stuck. Same for ejbyte's and teylyn's answers.